# How do you shuffle through an array to generate a random number that doesn't repeat?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, shuffle

I'm trying to shuffle to generate a random number from an array and splice, but keep getting undefined for the last element that's left in the array. Here, I can generate random numbers that do not repeat. Below is the code for the same.

```
    <body>
        <div id="bingo">
            <script>

                let numbers = new Set()
                        .add("B1")
                        .add("B2")
                        .add("B3")
                        .add("B4")
                        .add("B5")
                        .add("B6")
                        .add("B7")
                        .add("B8")
                        .add("B9")
                        .add("B10");

                let called = Array.from(numbers);

                let display = new Array();


                function getRandomNum()
                {
                    function rando()
                    {
                        for (let i = called.length - 1; i > 0; i++) 
                        {
                            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * called.length);
                            const number = called[i];
                            called[i] = called[j];
                            called[j] = number;

                            if(number) 
                            {
                                called.splice(j, 1);
                            }
                            
                            if(called.length < 0)
                            {
                                return;
                            } else
                                {
                                    return number;
                                }
                        }

                        
                    }

                    if(called.length === 0)
                    {
                        index = "No More Numbers";
                    }else
                        {
                            index = rando();
                                display.push(index);
                        }
                    document.getElementById('bingo').innerHTML = index;
                    
                }


                function show()
                {
                    for(let n = 0; n < display.length; n++)
                    {
                        document.getElementById('reveal').innerHTML += "<br/>" + display[n] + "<br/>";
                    }
                } 



            </script>
        </div>

        <div id="button">

            <button onclick="getRandomNum()">Random Number</button>

        </div>

        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <div id="reveal">

            <button onclick="show()">Numbers Called</button>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

My only issue is that when it gets to the last element of the original array, it generates `"undefined"` instead of a value.

Need help with fixing that part so that it displays `"No more numbers"` once all the elements have been randomly generared and removed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the for loop with this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < called.length; i++){
```

Comment: so I tried it with this loop, but I'm still getting "undefined" for the last element in the array, then I get the "No More Numbers" message. I have tried using "called.length + 1" to see if that changes anything, but still the same result. I'm guessing it has something to do with the shuffle since there will only be one element to "shuffle" by the end of the array. Is that possibly what's affecting it?

Comment: @p4yner56 I cannot seem to reproduce the undefined case that you mention. Please check here: https://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/QWLVKGK?editors=1001

Comment: it was actually my mistake, I had a typo I kept missing, other than that, code works perfectly. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to do your way, just do:

for (let i = called.length - 1; i => 0; i++)